# How to control Windows Phone 8 Silverlight app from PC

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, automation, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app written that I need to automate.  I'd like to do the following:

1. Start the app remotely from a PC + USB, preferably via command
2. Trigger the event handlers for certain button presses

Keep in mind that this is a WP8 *Silverlight* app.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you have an app running on both machines, you can pass information through a database that 1 writes to and the other checks for commands to run. Being SL, this of coarse would be via some type of web service.

Comment: you could look at using a WCF Service to communicate between both applications. you can essentially make your own small peer-to-peer "network"

Answer (score 0):

**This launches an app from PC:**

```
XapDeployCmd.exe /launch <Product ID/Xap FileName> <targetdevice[:param]>
```

You can get `targetdevice[:param]` from `XapDeployCmd.exe /enumerateDevices`. You also know the `Product ID` of your app.

This XapDeployCmd is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment`

Example

```
XapDeployCmd.exe /launch f8ce6878-0aeb-497f-bcf4-65be961d4bba /targetdevice:0
```

**To trigger event handlers**

- Install WAMP (or any server package) on your PC.
- Write a simple GET/POST script
- When a button is pressed, change a value in database
- From the other device, regularly poll for changes in the same database entry